# CLR detected an invalid program with powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, clr

I'm trying to send a Powershell script to a server and execute it. The server recieves the script but when I try to create the PS instance it crashes. I've looked around alot for simular cases but it seems to be specific most of the times.

```
public void processMsg(TcpClient client, NetworkStream stream, byte[] bytesReceived, int length)
        {    
            mstrMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length);
            mscClient = client;
            mstrMessage = mstrMessage.Substring(0, length);
            Console.WriteLine(mstrMessage);

            if (mstrMessage.Length > 8)
            {
                if (mstrMessage.Substring(0, 8) == "%SCRIPT%")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Script recieved.");
                    try
                    {
```

- On the line below i get the following exception: Common Language
  Runtime detected an invalid program.

  ```
                      PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
                      using (powerShellInstance)
                      {
                          powerShellInstance.AddScript(mstrMessage);
                          powerShellInstance.Invoke();
                          Console.WriteLine("Script executed.");
                      }

                  }
                  catch (InvalidProgramException)
                  {

                      throw;
                  }

              }
          }
  ```

Comment: I know nothing about calling Powershell in this way, but: Is it something to do with requiring a different .NET Framework version? For example, are you running as 2.0 but Powershell is trying to use something from 4.0?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I'm using Powershell 3.0 with the 4.5.1 framework. Checking this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847769.aspx it looks like I'm doing it right.

Comment: @yavolo Which version of System.Management.Automation.dll did you compile your host app against (1.0 or 3.0)?  And what version of .NET is the app compiled against - 4.5.1?  What version(s) of .NET are installed on the server?

Comment: @yavolo on the link you reference, did you see this warning `However, due to a change in the runtime activation policy in Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0, Windows PowerShell host programs that were written for Windows PowerShell 2.0 and compiled with Common Language Runtime (CLR) 2.0 cannot run without modification in Windows PowerShell 3.0, which is compiled with CLR 4.0.`

Comment: @KeithHill You are correct, the problem was that Windows Management Framework was outdated. When I installed 3.0 it worked perfectly. If you wish to answer I'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bits are: A) what version of System.Management.Automation.dll did you compile against, B) what version of .NET did you complete against and C) what versions of PowerShell and .NET are installed on the server.

It is likely your server is running an outdated version of the PowerShell so what you compiled against is different than what is available on the server.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old answer to a question, but how do you use System.Management.Automation if you must support PowerShell v2+? I want to compile against .NET 4.0 (guaranteed on server), and include System.Management.Automation with ANY version of PowerShell 2 or greater. What are my options?

Comment: @ferventcoder If you need to support v2, you'll have to compile against the 1.0 version of SMA.dll.  You should be able to run PS engine in a 4.0.  If you ever get to the point of supporting v3+, check out this blog post - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/12/12/powershell-sdk-reference-assemblies-available-via-nuget-org.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Finding the 1.0 SMA could be interesting. I think if folks were okay with automatically upgrading their computers to posh v3 it wouldn't be an issue. Most folks prolly wouldn't be okay with that though.